# Stripping symbols in release build on Mac fails

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, strip

When trying to create a release build of my plugin bundle, the linker fails to succeed because it cannot strip the symbols.

Here is the output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip: symbols referenced by indirect symbol table entries that can't be stripped in: <long path to binary here>
_SecKeychainAddGenericPassword
_SecKeychainAddInternetPassword
_SecKeychainFindGenericPassword
_SecKeychainFindInternetPassword
_SecKeychainItemCopyContent
_SecKeychainItemDelete
_SecKeychainItemFreeContent
_SecKeychainItemModifyAttributesAndData
_SecKeychainLock
_SecKeychainUnlock
_NSLog
_NSStringFromSelector
_NSTemporaryDirectory
_class_addMethod
_class_getInstanceMethod
_class_getInstanceSize
_class_getInstanceVariable
_class_getIvarLayout
_class_getSuperclass
_ivar_getName
_ivar_getOffset
<some other objective-c symbols here, all from system frameworks>
_objc_autoreleasePoolPush
_objc_msgSend
_objc_release
_objc_retain
```

Interestingly no symbols from the frameworks the project loads or symbols from my code show up here.

The strip style is set to "all symbols", which was the default.